# Add config directly into C# assembly

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I need develop some application, that will be distributed to user as a single executable file. User should click to some button like "Download" and get exe file, then he executed it, and upload results back to my site. App should not contain any installer or something like this, just run once and get result.

My application have a main executable like "myapp.exe" and several data files, that depends on current user. Now i have to generate SFX zip archive, that contains myapp.exe, datafiles and current user config. When user click "download", i'm adding user data to archive and provide it to user.

Problem is that SFX archive is very boring and difficult to maintain thing. I can't change it's interface, i can use only one or two zip libraries, that can create SFX arxhives.

Is there any way to use another container or pack user data into resources of my utility "on the fly"?

Comment: While not knowing what the user config may contain, or if the data files varies. But why don't you make the executable generate these files at first runtime? 
Perhaps maintaining the user data in a database, the app could retrieve the user characteristics and produce the files.
This is both flexible and easy.

Comment: App should be completly offline, user data is known only at the server side.

Server should provide utility with all data, used by application. Then app should work with this data and user desktop and provide result. Then user uploads it manualy back to site. There are some other constraints connected with it, but making such application is the only way to solve main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing that for an application where i needed to identify which user it was without asking for any credentials. Basically, some kind of token was bundled within application before download and then sent to the server.

From what i've found, there are 2 methods :

- Using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/): build the XML, call candle + light, send to client
- Making a single MSI and [editing its database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383481/Editing-an-MSI-Database) just before sending it to client

We chose MSI database editing for its simplicity of implementation, but i've seen WiX in production recently and the result is pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mono Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) to programmatically alter assemblies, including their resources. In your case, you could use it to modify your assembly pre-download to add/modify embedded resources that contain the data for the specific user.

```
byte[] userData = ...;
EmbeddedResource resource = new EmbeddedResource("UserData", ManifestResourceAttributes.Public, userData);
assembly.MainModule.Resources.Add(resource);
```

You can then read the added/modified resource(s) (at runtime, post-download) using [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).